# c#/.NET SQLite -- REINDEX not working?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I'm trying to reindex a table in a simple database that I created using SQLite.NET and VS2008. I need to reindex tables after every DELETE command and here is the code snippet I have written (it does not work):

```
SQLiteCommand currentCommand;
String tempString = "REINDEX tf_questions";
//String tempString = "REINDEX [main].tf_questions";
//String tempString = "REINDEX main.tf_questions";

currentCommand = new SQLiteCommand(myConnection);
currentCommand.CommandText = tempString;
currentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When run within my program, the code produces no errors, but it also doesn't reindex the "tf_questions" table. In the above example, you will also see the other query strings I've tried that also don't work.

Please help,

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a workaround for my problem. Consider the following code:

```
SQLiteCommand currentCommand;
String tempString;
String currentTableName = "tf_questions";
DataTable currentDataTable;
SQLiteDataAdapter myDataAdapter;

currentDataTable = new DataTable();
myDataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + currentTableName, myConnection);
myDataAdapter.Fill(currentDataTable);


//"tf_questions" is the name of the table
//"question_id" is the name of the primary key column in "tf_questions" (set to auto inc.)
//"myConnection" is and already open SQLiteConnection pointing to the db file

for (int i = currentDataTable.Rows.Count-1; i >=0 ; i--)
{
    currentCommand = new SQLiteCommand(myConnection);
    tempString = "UPDATE "+ currentTableName +"\nSET question_id=\'"+(i+1)+"\'\nWHERE (question_id=\'" +
        currentDataTable.Rows[i][currentDataTable.Columns.IndexOf("question_id")]+"\')";
    currentCommand.CommandText = tempString;

    if( currentCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() < 1 )
    {
        throw new Exception("There was an error executing the REINDEX protion of the code...");
    }
}
```

This code works, though I would have liked to have used the built-in SQL REINDEX command.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this for the sake of performance, consider this [answer](http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg06775.html):

> REINDEX does not help. REINDEX is only
>   needed if you change a collating
>   sequence.
>
> After a lot of INSERTs and DELETEs,
>   you can sometimes get slightly better
>   performance by doing a VACUUM.  VACUUM
>   improves locality of reference
>   slightly.

Comment: I need the indexes to be in order because it's easier to integrate that type of database into my target application. Thanks for responding.